# Angular 2/4 Access each member of a class and empty its value

Tags: angular

I have a class that has objects and members. After a successful operation, I want to reset all the members of the class.
Is there a way to achieve this without writing a for loop? I cannot set the class object to null, as it will break processing downstream.

```
for( var member in this.myService)
    {
      member = "";
    }
```

But when it encounters another object it fails. I will have to go through the members of that object, instead of that is there a way to reset all the members that belong in this class to "". Most members are strings, and the inner objects members are also string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Comment: `Is there a way to achieve this without writing a for loop` <= You have to either write code to empty out each property/field explicitly **or** you have to create a loop that iterates over the objects properties.

Comment: Sir, Thank you. I had something like that in mind. My question was , if there was a command in angular that would , clear out the object. The other challenge is, I have to cast and check if every object is not a string with the === and then loop through that object and clear it. I will try to do that and get back to you. Thank you for your help.